# How to clear all resources associated with SSL and TCP

Tags: c#, sockets, ssl, tcp

I've got software which creates and closes a lot of TCP streams, and communicates with other systems via SSL. It works correctly, except that after a few hours, connections start timing out, and I start getting a lot of IOExceptions (disconnected from the host). When I restart the software, the problem goes away.

I have made sure that the number of open TCP connections stays in range (via `ipProperties.GetActiveTcpConnections()`), and I'm assuming that there is no TCP port leak.

I think one way to fix the issue would be to simulate app restart by clearing all static resources associated with SSLStream and TCPClient.

Is there any good way to do it?

Comment: What OS are you using? What does `netstat -anp` in a command box / command shell tell you about tcp connections stuck in TIME_WAIT status and hogging ports?

Comment: @OllieJones windows server 2008

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/232493/lots-of-time-wait-connections-in-netstat-windows-server-2008

Comment: the issue may be related, but it goes away after I restart my application, the server remains online

Comment: Are you definitely disposing all your SSLStreams and TCPClients? With "using" constructs? You shouldn't have to recycle an application like that if you're disposing your IDisposable resources.

Comment: I'm not using  `using` since the TCPClients are long lived compared to the classes that use them, but I've taken precautions like registering every TCPClient and closing it after 5 minutes of inactivity. That didn't do anything to fix the issue. I'm also making sure to close all streams which originate from TCPClient

Comment: I think you should find the bug instead of looking to "reset ssl and tcp state". For example use TCPView.exe to see how many connections there are. Is the network saturated? Is the server disconnecting you? Post the full exception ToString.

Comment: @usr I'm logging connection count through the execution, and the number fluctuates in a range for a long time before the problem starts

Comment: Your comment answers only a fraction of my questions. That's not a good way to make progress.